# Why my ball Sprite doesnt always bounce on my Sprite bar?!

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some problems and I cant figure out how to fix them...
It is really simple game. A bar moved by the mouse and one ball is (or some balls) bouncing.
The user just need to keep the ball bouncing.

The user can choose how many balls he wants (1,2,3), the size of the bar (small, medium,large) and the speed of the balls (slow, normal, fast).

Problems:
- sometimes everything works fine, and sometimes the ball (or balls) just goes through the bar. Like if the collision function does not work. Is there any other way I can do?

- everytime there is a collision, the score should add 10 points for the total displayed on top of the screen, but this score is been overwriting all the time.

For this game be run, I just have to call the function (startGame) from other file (settings), where it also sends the value of number of balls, size of bar and speed of balls.

If anyone can help I appreciate.

Thanks

```
from livewires import games, color
from tkinter import*
import random


games.init(screen_width = 735, screen_height = 350, fps = 60)

class Bounce(games.Sprite):

    global total_score
    total_score = 0



    def update(self):

        global total_score
        if self.bottom == 315 and self.overlapping_sprites:
            self.dy = -self.dy
            total_score += 10

            the_score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, 
                                         color = color.gray,x = 700, y = 20)
            games.screen.add(the_score)

        if self.right > games.screen.width or self.left < 0: 
            self.dx = -self.dx

        if self.top < 0:
            self.dy = -self.dy

        if self.bottom == 400:
            lose_message = games.Message(value = " - GAME OVER -",
                                         size = 50,
                                         color = color.gray,
                                         x = games.screen.width/2,
                                         y = games.screen.height/2,
                                         lifetime = 300,
                                         after_death = games.screen.quit)
            games.screen.add(lose_message)


class Bar_moving(games.Sprite):
    def update(self):   

        self.x = games.mouse.x  
        self.y = 315

        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0

        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width


class have_settings():

    def __init__(self):

        global the_ball_speed
        global the_ball_number
        global the_bar_size

        if "the_ball_speed" not in globals():
            the_ball_speed = "normal"
        if "the_bar_size" not in globals():
            the_bar_size = "medium"
        if "the_ball_number" not in globals():
            the_ball_number = 1

    def set_all(self, number, size, speed):

        global the_ball_speed
        global the_bar_size
        global the_ball_number

        if speed in ("slow","normal","fast"):
            the_ball_speed = speed

        if size in ("small","medium","large"):
            the_bar_size = size

        if number in (1,2,3):
            the_ball_number = number



def startGame():

    call = have_settings()

    background = games.load_image("BG.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = background

#-------------------------------------SPEED
    sp_is = 0

    if the_ball_speed == "slow":
        sp_is = 2

    elif the_ball_speed == "normal":
        sp_is = 3

    elif the_ball_speed == "fast":    
        sp_is = 4

#-------------------------------------BALL NUMBER    
    if the_ball_number in (1,2,3):

        for n in range(the_ball_number):

            position_x_list =(50,150,250,350,400,450,500,550)
            position_x = random.choice(position_x_list)

            position_y_list =(50,100,150,200,225,250)
            position_y = random.choice(position_y_list)

            vert_speed_list = (-2,2)
            vert_speed = random.choice(vert_speed_list)

            ball_img = games.load_image("ball.bmp")
            ball = Bounce(image = ball_img,
                               x = position_x,
                               y = position_y,
                               dx = vert_speed,
                               dy = - sp_is)
            games.screen.add(ball)

#-------------------------------------BAR SIZE   
    if the_bar_size in ("small","medium","large"):
        if the_bar_size == "small":
            bar_pic = "bar_small.jpg"
        elif the_bar_size == "medium":
            bar_pic = "bar_medium.jpg"
        elif the_bar_size == "large":
            bar_pic = "bar_large.jpg"


    bar = games.load_image(bar_pic, transparent = False)
    the_bar = Bar_moving(image = bar, x = games.mouse.x)
    games.screen.add(the_bar)
    games.mouse.is_visible = False
    games.screen.event_grab = True 


    games.screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a greater than check rather than an equals check as follows:

```
if self.bottom >= 315 and self.overlapping_sprites:
               ^^
```

instead of

```
if self.bottom == 315 and self.overlapping_sprites:
```

This is because rarely will the ball's y position ever perfectly line up with the bottom. In some cases it may go from `y==314` to `y==316`. In such cases, your method above wouldn't work. Therefore, you should be a greater than test rather than an equality test.

You can apply similar changes everywhere else and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now it seems to be obvious...
But do you know why my scores are not been updated???
Thanks one more time

Comment: I changed to ...
the_score = games.Text(value = total_score, size = 25,color =color.gray,x = 700, y = 20)

actually it updates, but it prints over and over again on top of the last value ...overwriting..

Comment: @user3132508, you should clear the screen before you draw your text again. Standard rule of pygame